# Is it possible to force a user to like a Application?

Tags: iframe, facebook-like

Is it possible to add a Like button inside an app (iframe) to ensure the user likes the app and not the page that "ownes" the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can. But the user has to install your app in order to access the user's likes. Permission `user_likes` is required.